# Ionic add has-header and has-tabs-top automatically into <ion-content>?

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm creating a project using Ionic 1.3.2 and building to Android 5.1.1. The problem is after buiding the classes `has-header` and `has-tabs-top` are added into `<ion-content>` automatically and because this a space is beeing showing. I don't know why this happens and I don't know how to remove these classes or if there's another solution.

How could I solve this ?

**View**

```
<ion-view>

  <div class="item item-input-inset">
      <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" ng-model="pesquisar" placeholder="O que procura ?">
      </label> 
  </div> 

  <ion-content>

    <ion-list>      
        <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left"
                  ng-repeat="empresa in empresas | filter:pesquisar" 
                      ng-click="getEmpresa({{empresa.id}})" >


              <img ng-src='{{empresa.imagem}}'>
              <h2 class="customTitle">{{empresa.razaoSocial}}</h2>

              <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <ul>
                  <li ng-repeat="ce in empresa.categorias | filter:pesquisar" 
                      class="customListInline customCategoriaEmpresa">{{ce.descricao}}</li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="row row-bottom">
                  <div class="col col-25"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-thumbsup icon-24px"></i></a></div>
                  <div class="col col-25"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-chatbox icon-24px"></i></a></div>
                  <div class="col col-25">
                      <a href="tel:{{item.telefone}}"><i class="icon ion-ios-telephone icon-24px"></i></a>
                  </div>
              </div>


        </ion-item>
        <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="loadMore();" distance="1%" ng-if='!moreData'></ion-infinite-scroll>
   </ion-list>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image]

Comment: It's not nice, but I got around it by adding style="top:44px;" to the <ion-content> element.

Answer (score 2):

As per @MikeT's comment, but i think you want:

```
<ion-content style="top:0px">
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this attribute to your ion-content

> hide-nav-bar="true"

Comment: This doesn't work has-tabs-top is still there along with the extra unwanted space. :(